# How do you solve the differential equation $f'(x) = f(ax)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions

I was looking at $C^\infty$ functions that are not analytic anywhere. For that I was looking at solutions of $f'(x) = f(ax)$. There is such a function for $a = 2$. But how would you solve that differential equation in general, for any value of $a$?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did this question come from. Context please

Comment: Why don't you tell us your solution for $a=2$?

Comment: The solution for $a=2$ is Fabius' function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function

Comment: Fabius function $f(x)$ satisfies $f'(x)=2 f(2x)$, but $g(x)=f(\tfrac x2)$ gives $g'(x)=\tfrac 12 f'(\tfrac x2)=\tfrac 12 \cdot 2 f(x)=g(2x)$. So Fabius function, scaled horizontally, is a solution.